# I'm looking for an anime/movie that involved a plot with 2 boys and 1 girl. Had a piano. Something about different dimensions?

Tags: nerawareta-gakuen

This was either a short anime or animated movie.

3 main characters, as far as I remember. I remember that out of the 2 boys, one was a boy who was from a different planet(dimension?). He played the piano and it had strange effects on those around him. The other boy was human. The human boy and the girl were friends. This anime probably had a school setting.

I remember there being a lot of scenes involving the alien boy going into another dimension where there was always a bed(?) that he talked to. The boy's mission was probably (not sure!) to bring humans back to his home planet...

In the end, the 2 boys decided to leave earth so that alien guy could return to his home and the girl was left behind. As soon as the boys left, the girl lost all her memories about them.

Have been searching for ages now, but I always get Piano no Mori as a result back and that's not it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This sounds a bit like [*Alien Nine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Nine), though I think that features three girls. Might be worth a look for you anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I found it!!! It's Nerawareta Gakuen. Man, did I get the summary wrong, haha...

---

## [Nerawareta Gakuen](http://myanimelist.net/anime/14293/Nerawareta_Gakuen)

[image]

## Synopsis

Spring marks the start of another new school year at a junior high school in Kamakura. A new transfer student, Ryoichi Kyogoku joins the 8th grade. Kyogoku has a very special proficiency in telepathy and has been ordered by his father to use this ability to scan other people's minds and take over the school.

He instantly gains popularity at school from his good looks and charisma and he sets about taking control of the school. As people begin to fall under Kyogoku's spell, he covertly manipulates his followers and pushes aside anyone who gets in his way.

With the school almost completely under the control of Kyogoku, only one boy seems unaffected—Seki. Does Seki have what it takes to save everyone from the clutches of mind control?

Comment: Glad you found it! :) Don't forget that you can mark your own answer as the correct one (by clicking the checkmark to the left) to show that this question has been solved.